# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the promotion to any site that wants to participate.

Here's the run down:

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by 28 November 2012, so vote away on if you want hats.

<sup>(This has been shamelessly stolen from [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5240/69203).)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the mostly positive feedback received, Linguistics will participate!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to vote **yes**. After all, who doesn't like it, can still **opt out** as stated in this point: *"Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available."*

Answer (score 0):

I think the matter has little importance. Either way is fine by me. But, only to provide a different point of view from Alenanno's, I would vote **no**. This play with hats may well suited to a gaming site (and probably to others, as well). But to a science site as ours, it would be a bit off. A [users](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users) page full of weird avatar hats would seem, er... less than serious to a new user, for example.

Comment: For what it's worth, all sites are getting it (well those who accept it). I don't think it's going to hurt our reputation in that sense. Besides, not all users are forced to participate, anybody can opt out. I just see it as a way to encourage participation and commitment. But thanks for sharing your opinion!